# Cómo hago que el scroll funcione en una position absolute

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Ya tengo toda una página con **position absolute**, sucede que cuando esta llega al final no baja, el resto del contenido se queda abajo y no puedo bajar a verlo, ya he intentado metiendo el contenido en una etiqueta **div** con el **overflow** pero nada, no puedo cambiar la posición porque se daña y porque ya todo está armado y no tengo tiempo para ponerme a crear esa página desde 0. **¿Qué puedo hacer?**

```
div style="overflow-y: scroll;">---CONTENIDO CON POSITION ABSOLUTE---</div>
```

Comment: No debería ocurrir eso. ¿Puedes poner un [mcve] para poder revisar el código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto te debería funcionar

```css
    .overflow{
       position: unset !important;
       overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .contenido{
      position: absolute;
      width: 600px;
      height: 2000px;
      color: white;
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="overflow">
      <div class="contenido">
        <h1>---CONTENIDO CON POSITION ABSOLUTE--- </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```